# MVVM updating ListView when a new item is added via another view

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, refresh

This is the situation. I have a WPF project with MVVM. Let me try to explain it..

**PersonView.xaml** shows a ListView with all persons, behind this View there is the ViewModel **PersonViewModel.cs**. Here the ListView PersonList gets filled.

On the **PersonView.xaml** is also a button that opens another View, **NewPersonView.xaml** with the ViewModel **NewPersonViewModel.cs** behind it.

How can I refresh the ListView on **PersonView.xaml** when I click the save button on **NewPersonView.xaml** so when a new Person is added?

I can provide code if needed?

**EDIT:**  When I add a new Person it saves it in a sql database.

Comment: If your ListView is bound to an ObservableCollection, will happen automatically.  If it is not working that way for you then you need to provide your code so we can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: They both have to share the exact same view model.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is passing an Action to your NewPersonViewModel when initializing it:

```
private void AddPerson(Person per) {
    PersonList.Add(per);
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PersonList); // this wont be needed if you use ObservableCollection
}
```

NewPersonViewModel.Initialize:

```
private Action<Person> _addPersonAction;

Initialize(Action<Person> addPersonAction) {
    _addPersonAction = addPersonAction;
}
```

If you want to add a person you can just call this action.

**Edit:**

If you dont use IoC you can do something like this:
(pseudo code)

1. Add a event mothod like Button_OnClick in your PersonView.xaml.cs
2. `var view = new NewPersonView();`
3. `((NewPersonViewModel)view.DataContext).Initialize(((PersonViewModel)DataContext).AddPerson);`
   obviously AddPerson would have to be puplic then.

This solution is not clean, but should work, i recommend using castle windsor IoC.

**Edit 2:**

If you want to save changes in database, you can do something like this: `PersonList.CollectionChanged += ...` and then use `e.NewItems` to find the items you have to add to db and `e.OldItems` to find that ones to delete.

Do this in your PersonViewModel.